# How to build a string taking alternate characters from two equal length input strings?

Tags: java, string

My Question is-

Given two strings s1 and s2 of equal length as input, the expected output is a string which the 1st char from s1, then
1st char from s2, then 2nd char from s1, then 2nd char from s2 and so on. For e.g. if s1=”Outer”, s2 = “Space”, the output
is “OSuptaecre”.

I have done it with loops and I want to know if there is any other simple code for this program like use of string functions.

```
public class JoinChars {

    static String testcase1 = "Right";
    static String testcase2 = "Wrong";

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JoinChars testInstance= new JoinChars();
        String result = testInstance.join(testcase1,testcase2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public String join(String str1, String str2){
        String str3="";
        if(str1.length()>=str2.length()){
            for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
                str3+=str1.charAt(i);
                for(int j=i;j<str2.length();){
                    str3+=str2.charAt(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(str2.length()>=str1.length()){
            for(int i=0;i<str2.length();i++){
                str3+=str2.charAt(i);
                for(int j=i;j<str1.length();){
                    str3+=str1.charAt(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return str3;
    }
}
```

Comment: if it's complete use [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: Change the question title to something informative! Right now it is completely enigmatic.

Answer (score 6):

You mean something like this ?

```
String result = "";
for(int i=0; i<s1.length();i++){
  result += s1.charAt(i);
  result += s2.charAt(i);
}
return result;
```

Please note that s1 and s2 are two String input of equal length.

Comment: You posted 5 secs before me, +1 :)

Comment: @AmirBawab Yeah but it will not work when strings length will be different.

Comment: @IT_Philic the OP specified the strings would be of equal length.

Comment: It's mentioned : `Given two strings s1 and s2 of equal length as input,`

Comment: Oh sorry, then it'll be ok...but I also wanted to solve it for another      case

Comment: For strings with different length you can use the length of the largest.

eg.  `ìnt length =  s1.length() > s2.length() ? s1.length() : s2.length()` and iterate over this length variable: `for(int i=0; i<length; i++){`

Answer (score 2):

```
public String join(String str1, String str2){
    String str3="";
    if(str1.length()>=str2.length()){
        for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
            str3 += s1.charAt(i);
            str3 += s2.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    else if(str2.length()>=str1.length()){
        for(int i=0;i<str2.length();i++){
            str3 += s1.charAt(i);
            str3 += s2.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return str3;
}
```

That's easier

Comment: This would crash index out of bound at line "str3 += s2.charAt(i);" 
same goes to else if condition for s1

Answer (score 2):

//Program to merge alternate characters of 2 Strings

```
public class MergedString {

  public static String getMergedString(String a,String b){
    String mergedString="";
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
        mergedString=mergedString+a.charAt(i);
        if(i<b.length()){
            mergedString=mergedString+b.charAt(i);
          }         
    }
    if(a.length()<b.length()){
        mergedString=mergedString+b.substring(a.length());
    }
    return mergedString;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ms=getMergedString("abcd","xyztkhj");
    System.out.print("Merged String:"+ms);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can largely simplify this code by a creative use of `CharBuffer`s:

```
public static String join(final String s1, final String s2)
{
    final int len1 = s1.length(), len2 = s2.length();
    final CharBuffer buf1 = CharBuffer.wrap(s1);
    final CharBuffer buf2 = CharBuffer.wrap(s2);
    final CharBuffer longest = len1 > len2 ? buf1 : buf2;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len1 + len2);
    final int minlen = Math.min(len1, len2);

    for (int i = 0; i < minlen; i++) 
        sb.append(buf1.get()).append(buf2.get());

    return sb.append(longest).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution inspired by [Alexis C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587046/alexis-c), whose solution was good but he decided to delete it instead of editing it when I asked him why he used char arrays instead of working on the plain strings and before I had a chance to tell him he could edit his answer:

```
public static String join(String str1, String str2) {
    int length1 = str1.length();
    int length2 = str2.length();
    int commonLength = Math.min(length1, length2);

    StringBuilder mixedStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(length1 + length2);
    // Append the characters which both strings have, mixing them
    for (int i = 0; i < commonLength; i++) {
        mixedStringBuilder.append(str1.charAt(i)).append(str2.charAt(i));
    }

    // Append the remaining characters
    mixedStringBuilder.append(str1, commonLength, length1).append(str2, commonLength, length2);

    return mixedStringBuilder.toString();
}
```

It works with strings of equal size as well as for strings of differing sizes.

Here are some execution examples:

```
join("one", "TWO")          -> "oTnWeO"
join("BANANA", "apple")     -> "BaApNpAlNeA"
join("ORANGE", "pineapple") -> "OpRiAnNeGaEpple"
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add on to the question, if the strings are of different lengths. Use recursion until one of the substring is of length 1 which implies that we need to blindly copy the other substring and return.
The time complexity is O(length of the smallest string)

```
public static String alternate(String str1, String str2)
{
    String result= null;

    char first= str1.charAt(0);
    char second= str2.charAt(0);

    result= Character.toString(first )+ Character.toString(second);
    if(str1.length()>1 && str2.length()>1)
        result= result+ alternate(str1.substring(1),str2.substring(1));
    else if(str1.length()==1)
        return result+str2.substring(1);
    else if (str2.length()==1)
        return result+str1.substring(1);    

    return result;

}
```

Do let me know if my analysis is correct. Thanks.

EDIT

```
str1= input()
str2= input()

str3= str1+str2

result=''
loop_length= min(len(str1),len(str2))

for i in range(0,loop_length):
    result= result+str1[i]+str2[i]

if (len(str1)>len(str2)):
    result= result+str1[(loop_length):(len(str1))]
else:
    result= result+str2[(loop_length):(len(str2))]

print(result)
```

The above, I have tried in Python. This solution is easier to understand compared to my earlier java code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Merge{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a ="abc";
    String b ="def";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int alength = a.length();
    int belnth = b.length();
    if(alength==b.length()){
        for(int i=0;i<belnth;i++){
            sb.append(a.charAt(i));
            sb.append(b.charAt(i));
        }           
    }else if(alength>belnth){
        int j=0;
        for(j=0;j<belnth;j++){
            sb.append(a.charAt(j));
            sb.append(b.charAt(j));
        }   
        for(j=belnth;j<alength;j++){
            sb.append(a.charAt(j));
            //sb.append(b.charAt(j));
        }

    }else if(alength<belnth){
        int j=0;
        for(j=0;j<alength;j++){
            sb.append(a.charAt(j));
            sb.append(b.charAt(j));
        }   
        for(j=alength;j<belnth;j++){
            sb.append(b.charAt(j));
            //sb.append(b.charAt(j));
        }

    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for both equal size and unequal

```
public static String appendAlterChar(String a, String b) {
        String res ="";
        if(a.length()>=b.length()) {
            int j=0;
            for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
                res+=a.charAt(i);
                while(j<b.length()){
                res+=b.charAt(i);
                j++;
                break;
                }

            }
        }
        else if(a.length()<b.length()) {
            int j=0;
            for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++){
                while(j<a.length()) {
                    res+=a.charAt(j);
                    j++;
                    break;
                }
                res+=b.charAt(i);
            }

        }

        return res;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat two strings of any length alternative characters from each.

```
public class StringConcat
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    String s1 = "Ajay S";
    String s2 = "Meena AM";
    StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i=0;i<s1.length() || i<s2.length();i++)
    {

        /****No Condition *****/
        if(i<s1.length())
            sb1.append(s1.charAt(i));
        if(i<s2.length())
            sb1.append(s2.charAt(i));
    }

    for(int i=0, j=0 ;i<s1.length() || j<s2.length();i++,j++)
    {

        /******Escape Space Pick Up next char ******/
        if(i<s1.length())
        {
            if(s1.charAt(i)!=32)
                sb2.append(s1.charAt(i));
            else
                sb2.append(s1.charAt(++i));
        }

        if(j<s2.length())
        {
            if(s2.charAt(j)!=32)
                sb2.append(s2.charAt(j));
            else
                sb2.append(s2.charAt(++j));
        }           
    }

    System.out.println(s1+", "+s2+" ==> "+sb1);
    System.out.println(s1+", "+s2+" ==> "+sb2);     
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to import another library, then the solution would be apparently concise and slim.

[`zip` in lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#zip) could make it possible to solve this problem in one line code:

```
_.zip('Outer'.split(''), 'Space'.split(''))
  .reduce(function (prev, curr) { return prev + curr.join(''); }, '');
```

If you're running js code on some es6 support engines, you can even use arrow function to make the code much more simple:

```
_.zip('Outer'.split(''), 'Space'.split(''))
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.join(''), '');
```

In addition, [Lodash is possible in browser](https://lodash.com/), which means that the solution above can be taken into practice on both nodejs platform and browser engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ms = "";
    String fs = "kush";
    String fs2 = "mayank";

    if (fs.length() > fs2.length()) {  //if 1st string length is larger than 2nd
        for (int i = 0; i < fs2.length(); i++) {
            ms += fs.charAt(i);
            ms += fs2.charAt(i);
        }
        for (int i = fs2.length(); i < fs.length(); i++) {
            ms += fs.charAt(i);
        }
    } else if (fs.length() == fs2.length()) { // if both strings have same length
        for (int i = 0; i < fs.length(); i++) {
            ms += fs.charAt(i);
            ms += fs.charAt(i);
        }
    } else {
        if (fs2.length() > fs.length()) { // if 2nd string is larger than 1st
            for (int i = 0; i < fs.length(); i++) {
                ms += fs.charAt(i);
                ms += fs2.charAt(i);
            }
            for (int i = fs.length(); i < fs2.length(); i++) {
                ms += fs2.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(ms);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like below

```
    String s3 ="";
    int  length = s1.length()>s2.length()?s1.length():s2.length();
    
    for(int i =0; i<length; i++) {
        if(i<s1.length()) {
            s3 = s3.concat(s1.substring(i,i+1));
        }
        if(i<s2.length()) {
            s3 = s3.concat(s2.substring(i,i+1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its ok, but more that asked. The question was "equal length", so this could be simplified.

Answer (score -1):

**Pass two strings str1 and str1 of any length as input, the expected output is a string which takes the 1st char from str1, then 1st char from str2, then 2nd char from str1 and 2nd char from str2 and so on. For e.g. if str1=”Outer”, str2= “Space”, the output is “OSuptaecre”.**

```
//A function with two input parameter str1 and str2.
public static String stringConcate(String str1,String str2){
        //Creating a empty String variable that store the output String.
        String str3="";
        //Checking the input String is a valid String or not(It must not be empty or null).
        if(str1!=null && str2!=null && !str1.isEmpty() && !str2.isEmpty()){
               //Condition for, if both input String are of same size.
                if(str1.length()==str2.length()){
                    for(int i=0;i<=str1.length()-1;i++){
                        str3+=str1.charAt(i);
                        str3+=str2.charAt(i);

                    }
                }
                //Condition for, if str1 is greater than str2.
                if(str1.length()>str2.length()){
                    for(int i=0;i<=str1.length()-1;i++){
                        str3+=str1.charAt(i);
                        if(i<str2.length()){
                            str3+=str2.charAt(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Condition for, if str1 is smaller than str2.
                if(str2.length()>str1.length()){
                    for(int i=0;i<=str2.length()-1;i++){
                        if(i<str1.length()){
                            str3+=str1.charAt(i);
                        }
                        str3+=str2.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            return str3;

    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Makyen : I had added comment to explain the functionality and given the limitation as well.